# Tableau not pulling the right data from big query

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

For context I am attempting to make a list of "open" issues in tableau from github/zenhub data and eventually sort it by top ten longest running issues. The problem is that some of my closed issues in big query are showing up as open in tableau. [Big query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tH7f.png) , [Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMG7P.png). My big query is showing closed in this example but my tableau is not displaying it. Below is the SQL I wrote in big query to get the results.

```
`SELECT
 repo,
 ticket_number,
 title,
 assignee,
 state,
 pipeline,
 IF(state == "closed",IF(ABS(DATEDIFF(MAX(IF(assign_times IS NOT NULL,assign_times, created_at)), closed_at)) < 1,1,ABS(DATEDIFF(MAX(IF(assign_times IS NOT NULL, assign_times, created_at)), closed_at))),NULL) AS completion_time,
MAX(IF(assign_times IS NOT NULL, assign_times, created_at)) AS start_time,
MIN(created_at) AS created_at,
MAX(closed_at) as closed_at,
MAX(assign_times) AS assign_time,
MAX(points) AS points,
QUARTER(closed_at) AS quarter_closed,
YEAR(closed_at) AS year_closed
FROM
[icxmedia-servers:icx_metrics.issues_and_zenhub] AS historical,
(
SELECT
repository.name AS repo,
IF(issue.number IS NOT NULL, issue.number, pull_request.number) AS ticket_number,
FIRST(IF(issue.number IS NOT NULL, issue.title, pull_request.title)) AS title,
IF(issue.number IS NOT NUll, issue.assignee.login, pull_request.assignee.login) AS assignee,
pipeline.name as pipeline,
IF(MAX(IF(IF(issue.number IS NOT NULL, issue.state, pull_request.state) == "open",0,1)) == 1, "closed","open") AS state,
IF(issue.number IS NOT NULL, issue.created_at, pull_request.created_at) AS created_at,
MAX(IF(issue.number IS NOT NULL, issue.closed_at, pull_request.closed_at)) AS closed_at,
NULL AS assign_times,
MAX(estimate.value) AS points,
QUARTER(MAX(IF(issue.number IS NOT NULL, issue.closed_at, pull_request.closed_at))) AS quarter_closed,
YEAR(MAX(IF(issue.number IS NOT NULL, issue.closed_at, pull_request.closed_at))) AS year_closed
FROM
[icxmedia-servers:icx_metrics.gh_zh_data_production]
WHERE
issue.number IS NOT NULL
OR pull_request.number IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
repo,
pipeline,
ticket_number,
created_at,
assignee) AS prod
GROUP BY
repo,
ticket_number,
title,
assignee,
pipeline,
state,
quarter_closed,
year_closed
 ORDER BY
ticket_number DESC`
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection between Tableau and BigQuery does not always constantly update, i.e. Tableau will typically pull down a local copy of the table itself to visualize rather than send the query to BQ every time something changes.

That said, I think you need to update your dataset in the Tableau "Data Source" tab, as the underlying data in BQ has changed.